# how does compiler know the type of pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

```
double d = 1.1;
double *p = &d;
cout << *p;
int i = 1;
int * q = &i;
cout << *q;
```

In the code above, when we dereference the pointer `p`(cout<<*p;), how does the complier know the size of `*p`? I mean, if the size of double is 8 and the address of the `d` starts from 1000, how does the complier know that it should take the data from 1000 to 1007 whereas for `*q`, that it should take 4 bytes?

Since the sizes of `p` and of `q` are all 4, I don't know how the complier get the info about type from the pointer.

Comment: You told it the type when you declared the pointer.

Comment: `double *p` is a pointer to a `double` whose size is known. Don't confuse the size of the pointer with the size of the type it is pointing to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To clarify chris post.
When you declare `double *p`, you're explicitly telling the compiler that "I'm declaring a pointer that points to a double". During compilation, the compiler then remember that, in every part of the code that refers to `p` (following the rules of scope), `p` is a pointer to a double, and by extension, `p` is a pointer to a memory location that the same size as a double. So everywhere it sees `p`, the compiler knows "`p` is a pointer to a double of the size double".

Comment: Oversimplification, I'd say. But probably suits OP.

Comment: I agree it is an over-simplification. But trying to write out how C/C++ compiler handles types and pointer would probably be a multi-page long article. Granted, I'm not that good a explaining complicated concepts, so simple it is.

Comment: You can confirm this type inference by trying to output a `void *p`. The compiler will error, as it cannot infer the size of the memory you wish to dereference. You have to typecast the pointer first, to allow the compiler to dereference the correct memory size.

Comment: A bit of a fun addendum. You can do crazy stuff like `long *lp = static_cast<long *>(p)`, even if said `p` is pointing to `double` (maybe nonsense result unless you're doing something like fast inverse square root), `Cat` (an instance of a class Cat, for instance), or `bool` (congratulation, you're not reading part of the memory you're now supposed to, there may be seg-faults in your future. Hope you don't write to it).

Comment: @NathanOliver It's undefined by C/C++ standard, but not if you fully understand the system you're running on (for example, embedded system, x86/x64 system on Windows). The famous "Fast Inverse Square Root" method essentially exploit the IEEE float bit pattern to create a very fast approximation of an inverse square root before refining it. On embedded system, you use static_cast a lot to format a binary array (that you read, say, from a serial port) into a structure you can use.

Comment: Doing the insane is something that you just have to do some times, but... Look for other options first, profile to make sure it really did make things better, and leave huge expletive deleted comment warnings explaining what what you did, why you did it, and how it works on the given platform. Be explicit about the platform. So much as one compiler revision could make the magic stop working.